# What is the best way to implement 2 dimensional array in javascript whose size is not fixed?

Tags: javascript

For example if we have a list of topics and each topic has a list of questions and later on i want to iterate through all the questions..

Comment: How about a loop?

Comment: Is the list an array, or something else, like HTML elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for topics and inside an array for questions.

```
[
    {
        topic: 'Timetravel',
        questions: [
            'In Films?',
            'In Books?',
            // more questions
        ]
    },
    // more topics
]
```